# Exception Error: "Memory limit has been reached."

Tags: attributes, error, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0, error-log

I'm trying to edit my attributes and only one of the attribute codes is giving me the error: Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

This may be due to the recent up-gradation to `Magento 1.9.2`. I have checked the report log and it is saying this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:30:"Memory limit has been reached.";i:1;s:4517:"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `php.ini` config.
find `memory_limit`, set it to `1024M` like so:

`memory_limit = 1024M`

and also change `max_execution_time`:

`max_execution_time = 60`

also check manual:
[php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)